# Using a foreach loop for multiple

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have been making a little console app that will look up the the best sellers on a website.
I have created two HtmlNodeCollection variables.

```
        public void setup()
        {
        try
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = _web.Load(_url);
            Console.WriteLine("beginning " + _url);

            HtmlNodeCollection node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='b7907c3f23606bda85d1bf4da658198da2d954d3-carousel']/div/div/div/div/div/div/h5/a");
            HtmlNodeCollection price = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='price-info']/p");
            if (node != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in node)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There has been and exception thrown in setup " + e);
        }
    }
```

The foreach loop is working correctly but I am not sure how to then loop through the one for price. Is it possible to use operators on a foreach loop? If not is there  a way to loop through them both? Thanks for any help which you can provide

Comment: Could you show an example of the XML? There's probably a simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to go through two collections of the same length and pair the items. `Enumerable.Zip` does that:

```
nodes.Zip(prices, (n, p) => new { n, p });
```

Be aware that you will silently get wrong results if the collections are not aligned. You better assert before the loop that everything is well:

```
Debug.Assert(nodes.Count == prices.Count);
```